# Android SQLite cursor looping twice

Tags: cursor, android-sqlite

I have a problem with the android cursor looping twice, even though I know there is only one value returned in the cursor.getCount().

I'm using the following in the DBAdapter:

```
public Cursor getAllSubDetailsFromObsTable() {
Cursor c = mDb
        .rawQuery(
                "SELECT DISTINCT sub.sub_id, sub.complete, mobileobs.date, mobileobs.location, mobileobs.grid_ref, "
                        + "mobileobs.time, mobileobs.protocol_id, mobileobs.endtime FROM sub, mobileobs "
                        + "WHERE sub.sub_id = mobileobs.sub_id",
                null);
return c;
}
```

Then I call this within my worker class with:

```
db.open();
Cursor c = db.getAllSubDetailsFromObsTable();
while (c.moveToNext()) {
        String sub_id = c.getString(0);
        //Rest of real code <snipped>
        myArrayList.add(sub_id);
}
c.close();
db.close();
```

However, when I look at the contents of myArrayList, it has two identical values of sub_id. I have tried mucking about with c.moveToFirst() etc. etc. but I still get two values in the arrayList even though c.getCount() = 1!

Comment: I wonder if this is to do with onCreate and onResume. When I start the activity, I call the database work, which is also called onResume (to repopulate ListViews after changes). Looking at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html suggests that onResume is used during onCreate, so I maybe I should be using onRestart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally nailed this. It was to do with class variables and method variables. I had a class variable that was being populated by a method within onCreate that was also being called within onResume. Solution was to move the variable into the method. Stupid bug, easy to fix, difficult (for me) to find.